# How do I slow down an animation with Facebook Pop?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-pop

I'm animating a view on the X-axis using Facebook Pop's spring animation.  It works fine, except I can't seem to change the speed.  It seems that the velocity property is the only way to do this from what I've read, but no values I set for it seem to have any effect.  Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

```
    POPSpringAnimation *anim = [POPSpringAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:kPOPLayerPositionX];
    anim.velocity = @(100.);
    anim.springBounciness = 15;
    anim.toValue = @(self.scrollView.frame.size.width/2);
    anim.beginTime = .05 * i + CACurrentMediaTime();
    [thisView.layer pop_addAnimation:anim forKey:@"myKey"];
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try to experiment with those properties (of POPSpringAnimation class):

```
CGFloat dynamicsFriction
CGFloat dynamicsMass
CGFloat dynamicsTension
```

Comment: This should be marked as solved. Those are exactly the properties you need for this.

Answer (score 1):

The POPSpringAnimation `springSpeed` property is probably what you want. It's easier than having to mess with the 3 other lower level properties (as mentioned by Mateusz). It defaults to 12.